# How to add a css class to a tab on product view page from xml?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am adding tabs from xml to product view page, but I want to apply separate css class on one of the tab.

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" >                    
                    <alias>description_tabbed</alias>                 
                    <title>My Tab</title>             
                    <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>                    
                    <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>                
                </action>
```

How can I add class to it? I tried the following:

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" >                    
                    <alias>description_tabbed</alias>                 
                    <liParams>
            <class>myclassname</class> 
            </liParams>
                    <title>My Tab</title>             
                    <block>catalog/product_view_description</block>                    
                    <template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template>                
                </action>
```

Comment: this link may help you http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/178504/

Comment: @KeyurShah Thanks for the help but I already have tried this link and its not working for me. I guess it only works for top links.